# Typically how long it takes to finish one page/chapter of the Hebrew bible?

Tags: history, tanach, writing-printing, text, recording

What is the average time/day/months a prophet can finish writing one page or chapter before writing the next? I can't find a resource online other than how many years it took to finish the whole book.
I asked this question because I'm quite curious about Isaiah 7 & 8 where it says there a baby was born in chapter 7 then on 8 Isaiah's wife got pregnant. I just like to know the average recording interval of each page.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Chapters were much later addition and pages are not uniform among versions of the Prophets. I don't think anyone can answer this.

Comment: The first chapter took about 6 days (or several millennia according to some opinions...) :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't think it works that way. The recording isn't the issue. At various times in his life, the prophet received prophecy and wrote it down. It wasn't up to him when or if he would receive more. For instance, in Moses's books, there is an almost forty year gap in the book of Numbers without much notice at all (probably early on in Parshas Chukas near the section on Miriam's death) - then the entire book of Deuteronomy was given and written in about 37 days, from the first of Shevat till the seventh of Adar.

Comment: That's one opinion given, and the other opinion is that he wrote all of it at once in the end ([Gittin 60a](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%92%D7%99%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%A1_%D7%90))

Comment: @ba Not sure how that's relevant? It was given earlier, perhaps, just not ordered to be written down. Unless your point is that the actual writing didn't take long, but that was probably miraculous; he had to write it in seventy languages...

Comment: The question is about writing